# How to make RecyclerView item layout with different size with StaggerGridLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I have a recyclerView where I need to show only images from API with pagination(Paging3 library). I have to show the image with StaggeredGridLayout.I specify the span count 3 and the item layout width, and height to wrap content. But it wasn't working. I want a second item layout whichh is double size.  I have attached a snap that I want as my layout. Please help me, I am stuck.
**What I want**
[This is the screenshot I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWGQe.png)

**RecylerView**

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/searchHomeImageRv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout2"
    app:spanCount="3"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_image" />
```

**Item CardLayout**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:cardElevation="5dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:rippleColor="@color/black500">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/attention" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```